# How to display the names of my SQL Server tables in a listbox using vb.net?

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I want to show the names of the tables I have in my SQL Server database in a listbox using vb.net.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
 connetionString = "Data Source=ABDELOUAHED;Initial Catalog=table_creances;integrated security=true"
 connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

 sql = "select * from table_creances"

 Try
        connection.Open()
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        ds.Clear()
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        connection.Close()
        ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

`table_creances` is the name of my database.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sys.tables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use system view [sys.objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)

try this code:

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    connection.Open()
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM sys.tables", connection)
    Using ds = new DataSet()
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        with ListBox1
            .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            .DisplayMember = "name"
            .ValueMember = "name"
        end with
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Or better yet: for tables use `sys.tables`

Comment: i get system.data.grid.rows on my list box

Comment: did you set sql = "SELECT name FROM sys.tables" ?

Comment: thank you very muck it's working perfectly :)

Comment: but the question should be: how to set query as DataSource of LsListBox using vb

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your sql

```
sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"
```

Comment: i get system.data.grid.rows on my list box

Comment: Try setting DisplayMember and ValueMemeber of the listbox before assigning the datasource

    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME    
    ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

Comment: same problem system.data.grid.row